# Wrapping multiple C++ .dlls with multiple C# .dlls

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I am working on a project to wrap a multi-dll C++ SDK with C# trying to wrap each original C++ dll with separate C# dlls. I encountered an issue that if some common symbol in C++ library A is used in C++ library B and C, it is impossible to wrap. As this is a very frequent scenario in C++ apparently I miss something trivial. Having spent a few days I am still at loss and would appreciate any help how to move on.

The following simple sample reproduces the problem:
- class Point is supposed to be defined in library A
- class Triangle is supposed to be defined in library B which uses A
- class Quadrange is supposed to be defined in library C which uses A

```
"MyPoint.h"
class  MyPoint
{
public:

    MyPoint(double theX, double theY) : myX(theX), myY(theY) {}

    double X() const { return myX; }
    double& X() { return myX; }

    double Y() const { return myY; }
    double& Y() { return myY; }

private:

    double myX;
    double myY;
};

"MyTriangle.h"
#include "MyPoint.h"

class MyTriangle
{
public:

    MyTriangle(const MyPoint& theP1, const MyPoint& theP2, const MyPoint& theP3) :
        myP1(theP1),
        myP2(theP2),
        myP3(theP3) {}

    MyPoint P1() const { return myP1; }
    MyPoint& P1() { return myP1; }

    MyPoint P2() const { return myP2; }
    MyPoint& P2() { return myP2; }

    MyPoint P3() const { return myP3; }
    MyPoint& P3() { return myP3; }

private:

    MyPoint myP1;
    MyPoint myP2;
    MyPoint myP3;
};

"MyQuadrangle.h"
#include "MyPoint.h"

class MyQuadrangle
{
public:

    MyQuadrangle(const MyPoint& theP1, const MyPoint& theP2, const MyPoint& theP3, const MyPoint& theP4) :
        myP1(theP1),
        myP2(theP2),
        myP3(theP3),
        myP4(theP4) {}

    MyPoint P1() const { return myP1; }
    MyPoint& P1() { return myP1; }

    MyPoint P2() const { return myP2; }
    MyPoint& P2() { return myP2; }

    MyPoint P3() const { return myP3; }
    MyPoint& P3() { return myP3; }

    MyPoint P4() const { return myP4; }
    MyPoint& P4() { return myP4; }

private:

    MyPoint myP1;
    MyPoint myP2;
    MyPoint myP3;
    MyPoint myP4;

};
```

The triangle and the quadrangle are set respectively with three and four points.
Thus, both of the classes (MyTriangle and MyQuadrangle) use  class MyPoint.
All three classes are wrapped separately.For each of the classes have their interface file:

```
"MyPoint.i"
%module MyPointWrapper
%{
#include "MyPoint.h"
%}
%include <windows.i>
%include "MyPoint.h"

"MyTriangle.i"
%module MyTriangleWrapper
%{
#include "MyTriangle.h"
%}
%include "MyPoint.i"
%include "MyTriangle.h"

"MyQuadrangle.i"
%module MyQuadrangleWrapper
%{
#include "MyQuadrangle.h"
%}
%include "MyPoint.i"
%include "MyQuadrangle.h"
```

The command line interface was written  for each file:
C:\swigwin-3.0.10\swigwin-3.0.10\swig -csharp -c++ -namespace geometry -outdir C:\Geometrics\MyPointNet\Generated MyPoint.i
C:\swigwin-3.0.10\swigwin-3.0.10\swig -csharp -c++ -namespace geometry -I"C:\Geometrics\MyPointcpp" -outdir C:\Geometrics\MyTriangleNet\Generated MyTriangle.i
C:\swigwin-3.0.10\swigwin-3.0.10\swig -csharp -c++ -namespace geometry -I"C:\Geometrics\MyPointcpp" -outdir C:\Geometrics\MyQuadrangleNet\Generated MyQuadrangle.i

When I use the MyPoint class in C #:

```
using System;
using geometry;

namespace Example
{
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                MyPoint P = new MyPoint (3, 4, 5);
            }
        }
}
```

an error appears that says that each class contains a type of MyPoint:
The type 'MyPoint' exists in both 'MyTriangleNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
and 'MyPointNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

How to avoid such a situation, but having three fully functional classes in C #, on the condition that each of the classes will be wrapped separately?

Comment: I rolled back the question - the edits you made were a fault with my testing/answer due to a lack of C#/Windows knowledge, not (the very good) details in your question and it's better to have it written more like an encyclopedia entry than an interactive debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it there, however to simply refer to existing code without generating more you need to use `%import "modulename.i"` instead of `%include`, so your .i files become:

MyPoint.i:

```
%module MyPointWrapper
%{
#include "MyPoint.h"
%}
%include "MyPoint.h"
```

MyQuadrangle.i:

```
%module MyQuadrangleWrapper
%{
#include "MyQuadrangle.h"
%}
%import "MyPoint.i"
%include "MyQuadrangle.h"
```

MyTriangle.i:

```
%module MyTriangleWrapper
%{
#include "MyTriangle.h"
%}
%import "MyPoint.i"
%include "MyTriangle.h"
```

I'm not a C# expert by any means, so I was expecting that you'd have to use `%typemap(csimports)` or something else to make sure that e.g. MyTriangle.cs knew how to reference the MyPoint type which it refers to using an unqualified name, but at least when I tested it with Mono on Linux building a single executable that didn't seem to be needed:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
swig3.0 -csharp -c++ -namespace geometry -outdir MyPointNet MyPoint.i
swig3.0 -csharp -c++ -namespace geometry -outdir MyTriangleNet MyTriangle.i
swig3.0 -csharp -c++ -namespace geometry -outdir MyQuadrangleNet MyQuadrangle.i

g++ -Wall -Wextra -o libMyPointWrapper.so MyPoint_wrap.cxx -shared -fPIC
g++ -Wall -Wextra -o libMyQuadrangleWrapper.so MyQuadrangle_wrap.cxx -shared -fPIC
g++ -Wall -Wextra -o libMyTriangleWrapper.so MyTriangle_wrap.cxx -shared -fPIC

mcs run.cs */*.cs && ./run.exe
```

All worked correctly once I'd changed your example usage to call a constructor for MyPoint that existed (2-arg). I also added a quick test for MyTriangle in:

```
MyTriangle T = new MyTriangle(P,P,P);
```

Additionally to make this work across multiple assemblies you'll need to do [a little more work, as outlined in the documentation, to change](https://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CSharp.html#CSharp_multiple_modules) the visibility of some of the internals from `internal` to `public`. You only need to do this inside modules that are imported, so in this instance MyPoint.i becomes:

```
%module MyPointWrapper
SWIG_CSBODY_PROXY(public, public, SWIGTYPE)
SWIG_CSBODY_TYPEWRAPPER(public, public, public, SWIGTYPE)
%{
#include "MyPoint.h"
%}
%include "MyPoint.h"
```

Note that the documentation suggests some better workarounds than just making it public. If it were my production code I'd look into those.

Comment: Thank you very much for offering a hint.
After I added a %module into Triangle.i file I ran into the access problem to methods of MyPoint class
from the code generated for Triangle (same for Qudrangle). The original post was edited with more details.

Comment: @KKrill if you run SWIG with `-Wall` it warns rather a lot about `internal` being a reserved word in C#. My guess is that it's something related to that.

Comment: Actually maybe not, seems it's some C# modules thing I've not got experience with before. Will dig a little more.

Comment: Got it. One edit coming up. Turns out it was exactly the issue I'd mentioned  before showing it compiling with Mono, but with a neater solution already in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. It helped me to solve my problem!